# Fix buttons on screen

Tags: spritekit, swift

I've  added buttons and SKCameraNode for my player. I got problem. When player moving left/right/jump all buttons dont follow for him.

**UPDATE**

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

```
var player: SKSpriteNode?

let buttonDirUp = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "button_dir_up")
let buttonDirLeft = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "button_dir_left")
let buttonDirDown = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "button_dir_down")
let buttonDirRight = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "button_dir_right")

var pressedButtons = [SKSpriteNode]()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5)

    userInteractionEnabled = true



    player = self.childNodeWithName("player") as? SKSpriteNode

    buttonDirUp.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150)
    buttonDirUp.zPosition = 2
    buttonDirUp.setScale(2.0)
    buttonDirUp.alpha = 0.2
    self.addChild(buttonDirUp)

    buttonDirLeft.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100)
    buttonDirLeft.zPosition = 2
    buttonDirLeft.setScale(2.0)
    buttonDirLeft.alpha = 0.2
    self.addChild(buttonDirLeft)

    buttonDirDown.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
    buttonDirDown.zPosition = 2
    buttonDirDown.setScale(2.0)
    buttonDirDown.alpha = 0.2
    self.addChild(buttonDirDown)

    buttonDirRight.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 100)
    buttonDirRight.zPosition = 2
    buttonDirRight.setScale(2.0)
    buttonDirRight.alpha = 0.2
    self.addChild(buttonDirRight)
}

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {

                if button.containsPoint(location) && pressedButtons.indexOf(button) == nil {
                    pressedButtons.append(button)
                }
            }
        }

        for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {
            if pressedButtons.indexOf(button) == nil {
                button.alpha = 0.2
            }
            else {
                button.alpha = 0.8
            }
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

            for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {

                if button.containsPoint(previousLocation)
                    && !button.containsPoint(location) {

                        let index = pressedButtons.indexOf(button)
                        if index != nil {
                            pressedButtons.removeAtIndex(index!)
                        }
                }

                else if !button.containsPoint(previousLocation)
                    && button.containsPoint(location)
                    && pressedButtons.indexOf(button) == nil {
                        pressedButtons.append(button)
                }
            }
        }

        for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {
            if pressedButtons.indexOf(button) == nil {
                button.alpha = 0.2
            }
            else {
                button.alpha = 0.8
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

            for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {
                if button.containsPoint(location) {
                    let index = pressedButtons.indexOf(button)
                    if index != nil {
                        pressedButtons.removeAtIndex(index!)
                    }
                }
                else if (button.containsPoint(previousLocation)) {
                    let index = pressedButtons.indexOf(button)
                    if index != nil {
                        pressedButtons.removeAtIndex(index!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {
            if pressedButtons.indexOf(button) == nil {
                button.alpha = 0.2
            }
            else {
                button.alpha = 0.8
            }
        }
    }



override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches! {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

        for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {
            if button.containsPoint(location) {
                let index = pressedButtons.indexOf(button)
                if index != nil {
                    pressedButtons.removeAtIndex(index!)
                }
            }
            else if (button.containsPoint(previousLocation)) {
                let index = pressedButtons.indexOf(button)
                if index != nil {
                    pressedButtons.removeAtIndex(index!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for button in [buttonDirUp, buttonDirLeft, buttonDirDown, buttonDirRight] {
        if pressedButtons.indexOf(button) == nil {
            button.alpha = 0.2
        }
        else {
            button.alpha = 0.8
        }
    }
}



override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
            if pressedButtons.indexOf(buttonDirUp) != nil {
        player!.position.y += 9.0
    }
    if pressedButtons.indexOf(buttonDirDown) != nil {
        player!.position.y -= 9.0
    }
    if pressedButtons.indexOf(buttonDirLeft) != nil {
        player!.position.x -= 9.0
    }
    if pressedButtons.indexOf(buttonDirRight) != nil {
        player!.position.x += 9.0
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you, maybe show us some code (If you have, I don´t know how that tool works), if not, maybe some screenshots?

Comment: @Mayuso Sorry. I've added code.

Comment: @Mayuso i thought about SkCameraNode fot buttons. No?

Comment: Why do you mention SKCameraNode? I don't see you using that anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the buttons as a child of the player. Instead of:

```
self.addChild(buttonDirUp)
```

it would be

```
player.addChild(buttonDirUp)
```